# Algebraic Topology: Question on meaning of $f_t \vert A$ where $A \subseteq X$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am goingAlgebraic Topology: Question on meaning of $f_t \vert A$ where $A \subseteq X$? through Allen Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book and noticed the use of
$f_t \vert A$ for some subspace $A$ of a topological space. I searched online but cannot quite find what the above expression means. I am guessing it has to do something with "a function dividing a subspace." I am not to sure what that would mean though.

Comment: I would say that $f_t\vert_A$ is the restriction of a map $f_t:X\rightarrow Y$ to the subspace $A\subseteq X$, if not explicitly stated otherwise…

Comment: Yep, @JonasLinssen that makes sense! Thank you.